# How should we tag region-specific questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Given the nature of this community (laws strongly influence freelance work, and laws are very different from place to place), I think that country tags might be important as well as state tags for those countries with several different states like USA and Canada.

But for the USA, the ideal state tag would be a *capitalized* two-letter abbreviation (RI for Rhode Island, MA for Massachusetts), and I don't know how to force the tags to be all-caps (they seem to automatically default to lowercase, and ri is perhaps not an obvious tag whereas RI might be an obvious tag for most US residents.

How does one force a tag to be all-caps?

Comment: Why would that be ideal? What's wrong with [tag:Rhode-Island] or [tag:Minnesota]?

Comment: I think fewer letters to represent an idea is always ideal. I know there's some kind of auto-completion software in the tags field, but if it can be done uniquely in two letters, why make it twelve?

Comment: State-specific questions might turn out to be too localized in the long run.

Comment: Related meta discussion: [Overcoming the location specificity of questions](http://meta.freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/53/overcoming-the-location-specificity-of-questions)

Answer (score 11):

Due to Stack Exchange's audience, I would recommend simply tagging the question [usa](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa) and mentioning the state (as this is a *specific* part of the question, it should not be a tag; a tag is supplementary, not the actual content of the question. On the other hand, this could be argued and discussed all day).

As for capitalization, tags are lowercase because of the Stack Exchange engine; by default, all tags will be `.lower()`ed (and spaces will be converted to `-` if they aren't treated as separators). If we really need tags to be uppercase, we could have the first round of moderators appointed by Stack Exchange to ask the development team to implement this.

However, I don't really think it's necessary to use capitals (I am British however, and I don't have too much experience with state-specific workplace problems as a result, so feel free to disagree)

**Edit**: money.stackexchange uses [united-states](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) as their USA tag. We'll need to pick one and stick to it.

Comment: Looking at the tag list seems to confirm the wisdom of avoiding two-letter state abbreviations. The "ri" is not at all intuitive as Rhode Island. Unless there would be so many Rhode Island questions as to warrant a tag, I agree just putting the state name in the question, preferably in the title. If state tages ever were needed, spelling out the state would be best.

Answer (score 2):

It may be too early to know for certain if location-based tags are needed, so it may be wise to hold off on them for now, as it could needlessly complicate tagging later down the road.

As Hiroto mentions, what's most important is the content, not the tags. If a question applies only to a person living in Britain, then the asker should be sure to make that clear in the question. Consider that many visitors who come to the site from Google searches may not be familiar with the tagging system and may overlook them when reading answers to a question they found while surfing the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

As [Hiroto](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/users/58/hiroto) mentioned, if `Freelancing Beta` has users from all over the world, [usa](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa) may very well suffice. Other options, could be to use [rhode-island](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rhode-island) or [usa.ri](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa.ri). That said, I am not sure how useful such a tag would be. I personally am not going to favorite the [minnesota](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minnesota) or [usa.mn](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa.mn) tag, because that's where I do business, and I am not sure how often I will even think to include it in a tag search.

As for the main question you asked - I believe [Hiroto](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/users/58/hiroto) answered it - it has to do with the default `Stack Exchange` site engine.