# Multiple useful location-based answers

Tags: discussion

I have asked [this question](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/207/does-the-type-of-payment-method-reflect-the-implied-professionalism-of-a-freelan) that received multiple answers. Some of the answers are region specific. Should the question be duplicated for each region? Or should I update the question with a region specific tag (usa)?

Answer (score 3):

As I said [here](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15/58) and [here](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4/58), tags shouldn't be used for information critical to the question: they should be supplementary, not an important part of the question.

Indeed, you should probably edit the question and *specifically* mention the region in the question (or even in the title, if you can work it in there).

If you don't mention a region, usually your question will be way too broad, and will result in some of the newer users to SE answering with whatever region they are from, rather than doing what we expect on Stack Exchange: that people comment and ask for clarification.